# Improving my method for evaluating the limit of this function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I could do with some help on the following question.

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)-\tan^2(x)}{(x-\pi)^4}
\end{equation*}

I've calculated the result using l'Hopital 4 times, but I'm fairly sure that can't be the best method of solving this problem. I'll just write down the last step to save a lot of typing.

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{-8\cos^2(x)-16\sec^6(x)+8\sin^2(x)-88\sec^4(x)\tan^2(x)-16\sec^2(x)\tan^2(x)}{4!}=-1
\end{equation*}

Whilst this works, it's not nice. I've tried looking for ways of doing it with trig identities, but I've not managed to find any.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If I may suggest : if you suspect that  L'Hopital needs to be applied more than two or three times, try to find another way. I  checked your result and I admire your patience doing all this work. Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, I knew as soon as I saw the $$(x-\pi)^4$$ in the bottom of the equation that L'Hospital wouldn't be a good way of doing it, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out a better way of doing it. It seems quite obvious now that @labbhattacharjee has said it (and thanks to him), I was caught up in trying to solve it with a trig identity... The calculation of the derivative isn't too bad when you ditch proper notation and just scribble down some letters for the different trig functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\pi-x=y$ to get $$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2y-\tan^2y}{y^4}
=-\left(\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y\right)^4\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{y\to0}\cos^2y}$$

as $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin y,\tan(\pi-y)=-\tan y$

and $\sin^2y-\tan^2y=-\dfrac{\sin^2y(1-\cos^2y)}{\cos^2y}=\cdots$

Comment: This expansion is just almost right. $\sin^2 y - \tan^2 y$ is not $\frac{\sin^2 y \left( 1 - \cos^2 y\right)}{\cos^2 y}$, but $\frac{\sin^2 y \left( \cos^2 y - 1 \right)}{\cos^2 y}$. This gets you the minus sign in $- \frac{\sin^4 y}{\cos^2 y}$.

Comment: @jordix, Thanks for your observation.